# Current sense amplifier for high voltage (100-150V) low current (20 mA) application

Tags: amplifier, current-measurement, low-side

I have an application where I need to measure the current on a relatively high voltage rail. The problem is that the current on the rail is quite low, only about 20 mA.

Because of the high voltage, high side sensing isn't an option. Has anybody got any experience with low side current sensing in high voltage, low current applications? Which current sense amp would you suggest/how would one go about this?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: 100 Volt is not high voltage. Isolated high side sensing is still open.

Comment: "Which current sense amp would you suggest?" Shopping questions are quickly closed so you may wish to remove that from your post. See [On-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Welcome to EE.SE. Take the [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Comment: Well it wasn't so much a shopping question as it was how would one go about it. The isolated high side sensing seems like a valid option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could easily and safely be done with a small Hall effect current transducer and there are many manufacturers.

[image]

*Figure 1. A selection of current sensors.*

They come in a variety of shapes and sizes and, while they resemble AC current transformers their principle of operation is quite different.

- They require DC power.
- They give out a low-voltage signal (rather than a current) proportional to the 
  primary current.
- Like a CT you can wind multiple turns through the device to increase the sensitivity. For example, if you find a device with 200 mA full-scale sensitivity then wind 10 turns through it for full-scale at 20 mA.

Note that the devices with three or four wires emerging from the centre of them can have the wires connected all in parallel for a high-current, single-turn arrangement or in series for low-current, 3 (or 4) turn, or any combination you can come up with.

Comment: This is a great idea, but i'm having trouble finding anything that would be precise enough. There are low current options, but they usually come in an sealed SMD package, with an internal coil, so you just connect leads to it.

Comment: There is no precision specification in your question. Be careful with the SMD type. They are likely to be one through-lead rather than a coil and may have low breakdown voltage between the wire and the sensor. Please unaccept my answer until you get what you really need. Wait for the globe to spin once or twice before accepting as it encourages others to answer and you'll probably get a range of alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzNtBF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you have ISOLATION requirements (none were stated), or linearity requirements (again, none were stated), or accuracy requires (none given),
this transistor circuit may or may not suffice.

The bandwidth of this circuit will be quite high.